# how to create randomness to explosion effect?

Tags: modifiers

Guys i tried to create a breaking soap bubble effect using blender using particles and explosion modifier. The render looks artificial and couldn't match the real effect.I think certain level randomness in the particles will make it look better.

Here is a link to the render:
https://youtu.be/AuaZzz7MqT0 (particles are emitted from the faces)

I tried the same by emitting the particles by volume but it gives a cut glass effect to the bubble
Here is a image when particles are emitted by volume:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtG5g.jpg